# How do I import a DynamoDB table that has a replica in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb

I created a DynamoDb table with the below script in terraform.

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "GameScores" {
  name           = "GameScores"
  billing_mode   = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key       = "UserId"
  range_key      = "GameTitle"

  attribute {
    name = "UserId"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "GameTitle"
    type = "S"
  }


  replica {
    region = us-east-2
    propagate_tags = true
  }

  tags {
    env = prod
  }
 
  stream_enabled = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES" 
}
```

I don't have the Terraform state file and I want to import this resource.

I tried the below but it only imported the main table and not the replica:

```
terraform import aws_dynamodb_table.GameScores GameScores
```

When I do a `terraform plan`, I see that its going to delete the old replica and recreate a new replica.

How do I import this replica with the above terraform script? What steps and in what order do I need to execute to import the above resource?

Comment: Add `lifecycle { ignore_changes = [replica] }` to your current TF plan, remove the `replica` property and then create a new [`aws_dynamodb_table_replica`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table_replica) and import it using the main table region. Does that still ask you to recreate the replica?

Comment: This worked great. Please write an answer, I will upvote. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below to your current TF plan:

```yaml
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [replica]
}
```

and remove:

```yaml
replica {
    region = us-east-2
    propagate_tags = true
}
```

Create a new [`aws_dynamodb_table_replica`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table_replica) resource and [import](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dynamodb_table_replica#import) it using the main table region e.g.

```bash
terraform import aws_dynamodb_table_replica.GameScoresReplica GameScores:eu-west-1
```